# How to set value and `disabled` properties to `new FormControl()`?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Here is my function, where I need to add properties as `disabed` and `value` how to do that? also `validation` should be added if requried.

```
 formBuilder(form, props) {
        let { required, disabled, value } = props;
        const formControl = new FormControl();//how to add?
       
        if (required) {
            formControl.setValidators([
                Validators.required,
                this.validate.plainText,
            ]);
        }
        form.addControl(props.controlName, formControl);
    }
```

getting props as:

```
       {
    "controlName": "userName",
    "validateType": "plainText",
    "elementType": "text",
    "placeHolder": "User Name 0",
    "value": "sample",
    "required": false,
    "disabled": true,
    "errors": {
        "required": "User Name must required"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please reproduce this issue in stackblitz. [Here is a link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5vmxmc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) where I tried to reproduce the issue but it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Like this :

```js
formBuilder(form, props) {
  const { required, disabled, value } = props;
  const validators = [this.validate.plainText];
  if (required) validators.push(Validators.required);
  const formControl = new FormControl({ value, disabled }, validators);
  form.addControl(props.controlName, formControl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    formBuilder(form, props) {
      let { required, disabled, value } = props;
      const formControl = new FormControl(value);//how to add?

      if (required) {
        formControl.setValidators([
          Validators.required,
          this.validate.plainText,
        ]);
      }

      if (disabled) {
        formcontrol.disable();
      }

      form.addControl(props.controlName, formControl);
    }
```

Comment: When i assign `value`  as variable it's not working. but if I hardcode it woks?!!

Comment: What value does your `props` have? please share the result of `console.log(props);`.

Comment: -> props added with question, may be change deduction required?

Comment: it look like, dynamically updating the value is not working. because the `reactiveForm` not deducting the update. any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The FormControl constructor is heavily overloaded.

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#constructor

There are 2 non-deprecated signatures, each with union types

```
new <T = any>(
    value: T | FormControlState<T>, 
    opts: FormControlOptions & { nonNullable: true; }
): FormControl<T>

new <T = any>(
    value: T | FormControlState<T>,
    validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn | FormControlOptions | ValidatorFn[],
    asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[]
): FormControl<T | null>
```

From here you can use typescript to work out what you can supply in the constructor.

Examples:

```
const formControl = new FormControl(null) // 2nd signature
const formControl = new FormControl(val) // 2nd signature, implicitly typed

// 2nd signature, implicitly typed, required
const formControl = new FormControl(val, Validators.required) 

// 2nd signature, explictly typed
const formControl = new FormControl<IMyInterface>(val)

// 1st signature, explictly typed, not nullable
const formControl = new FormControl<IMyInterface>(val, { nonNullable: true })

// 1st signature, explictly typed, not nullable, required
const formControl = new FormControl<IMyInterface>(val, 
    { 
        nonNullable: true,
        validators: Validators.required
    }
)

// 1st signature, explictly typed, not nullable, disabled
const formControl = new FormControl<IMyInterface>(
    { value: val, disabled: true }, 
    { nonNullable: true }
)
```